# CSS How Do I Make the Text Inside Of a Textfield Unselectable (until first character entered) and Have A Left Margin Of 5px

Tags: javascript

I want to replicate the sign up form the way google has it:
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&hl=en
But I do not know how to turn the text inside the field unselectable. Here is the rub: I have to make textfield editable so I can't use readonly. See the link please if you need clarification. 
Also, I don't know how to give the text inside the field margins

Here is what I have so far:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="validateName(this)" id="first" name="firstName" class="nameSignup" value="First">
```

CSS:
    #first {
    color: grey;
    }

Javascript:

```
function validateName(id){
var str = id.value;

if(str == ""){
    id.value = "First";
    $(id).prop('selectionStart', 0)
                 .prop('selectionEnd', 0);
            //psudo code
             turn text grey
             turn text unselectable
             margin-left: 10px;
}else{
        //Pseudo code
        erase the default value
        turn text black
        turn text editable
        margin-left: 0px;
        check if the character is valid (not @, #, $, etc)
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find any answers useful Please mark as answer by selecting the tick mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 placeholder attribute. This is not supported in older browsers though.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="validateName(this)" id="first" name="firstName" class="nameSignup"  placeholder="First">
```

[Support](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)
For crossBrowser compatibilty probably you can check **[this](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/creating-a-cross-browser-form-field-placeholder/)**